# How to distinguish syslog(2) and syslog(3)?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I see that there are syslog(2) and syslog(3).

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syslog.2.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html

Since they have the same function time, I don't see how the linker can distinguish them at link time. Could anybody help me understand how the linker correctly resolve the object code under the hood? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.. syslog(2) has to be called using  klogctl() wrapper or using syscall() at your own peril.. syslog(3) is the only definition present in the C library.